# How to run a specific testsuite/test of Robot framework on Jenkins CI with maven plugin

Tags: maven, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

I am tring to create a job that can help in running a specific test suite on CI and not the whole set of tests.How can I do that.I know I have to use run command,but not sure how to use it.

Comment: Are you aware of this documentation? http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/acceptance-test-mojo.html

Comment: Ya,I saw this.But the problem is that the documentation does not give clear examples.I have tried to use it.But it does not work the way I want.So I am looking for examples.

Comment: OK, did some more digging and perhaps that the POM example in this [tutorial](https://blog.codecentric.de/2010/03/robot-framework-fachtests-in-eclipse-entwickeln-und-mit-maven-ausfuhren/) will provide some insight. In addition I found this Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026891/how-to-exclude-test-suites-in-robot-framework-we-are-using-maven) that highlights how to set Suites and Tags. Something you're looking for. Again, not tested. This is another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32115088/using-robotframework-python-libraries-in-mvn-projects).

Answer (score 0):

The Robot Framework Guide has a seperate section on [Command Line Options](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#all-command-line-options).

An example (for Windows):

```
python -m robot.run -P C:\Python27\lib\site-packages -s MyFolderName.RobotFileName -t "MyFolderName.RobotFileName.Test Case Name" C:\Workspace\MyFolderName
```

Comment: I am using maven plugin of robot framework.So,need maven command to do so.